# Cannot post here

Tags: discussion

I just joined and am interested in certain questions, but there seems to be a 'Catch 22' blocking me – I have to achieve '50 reputation' to comment here at all, and this status is achieved by commenting, which without a '50 reputation' status, I may not do.

I have had a serious interest in and, indeed, love for the German language and its literature since my teenage days (which are longer ago that I would care to admit to!)

Wie schaffe ich das?

Comment: Very simply: ask questions, or give answers. Over time you will get reputation points that then allow you to post comments, too. - Oder sagen wir es so: Es ist ganz einfach: Stelle (gute) Fragen oder beantworte welche (gut), dann sammelst du mit der Zeit Punkte, und in Kürze kannst du dann auch Kommentare veröffentlichen. Um Fragen zu stellen oder Antworten zu geben, brauchst du keine Punkte. Nur für Kommentare brauchst du welche.

Comment: Since then s is a Q&A site, not a discussion site, comments are not seen as a central part. Anyway: Willkommen!

Comment: Antworten und Kommentieren sind 2 unterschiedliche Dinge und in unterschiedlichen Seitenbereichen vorzunehmen. Im Alltag spricht man auch von Antworten, wenn es Kommentare sind, v.a. wenn keine Frage gestellt wurde ("Oma antwortete mit einem 'Pffft' auf meine Frage, ob Papa wieder betrunken sei"). Man kann auch umgekehrt eine Antwort als Kommentar bezeichnen: ("Wann hat die Regierung mal ein Sicherheitsgesetz zurückgenommen?" fragte Erna. "Dazu hat noch jeder das Rückrat gefehlt!" kommentierte Phil.)

Answer (score 5):

Together with all other sites of the Stack Exchange network German Language  follows rules that evolved over the years for guaranteeing these sites' success.

One of these rules is reputation limits for chat and for comments. Reasons why we introduced this can be read in the following concise post:

- [Why do I need 50 reputation to comment? What can I do instead?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead)

Let me quote the bullet points published there:

> - There are big problems with spam. Automated filters cannot catch all of it.
> - Even among the real comments, most would either say "I have the same problem" or "I agree". Such comments do not add any value, and have to
>     be manually removed.
> - Comments are very painful to moderate. Stack Exchange sites have a process of community moderation (voting, flagging, review queues) that
>     works great for questions and answers, but not so much for comments.
>     Comments cannot be downvoted or closevoted, nor searched (nor do we
>     want that).
> - Comments are second class citizens on the Stack Exchange network, not designed to hold information for all eternity. They may get
>     cleaned up at any time. Generally, **truly important information
>     should be incorporated into an answer of its own anyway**.

But there is no worries, really. It is easy - very easy - to gain reputation and privileges associated with them by:

- editing existing posts (+2)
- asking good questions (+5)
- providing good answers (+10)

Each of these tasks can be done with zero reputation - even unregistered users can do this. Soon you will have enough reputation points to [talk in chat](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/chat) or to [comment everywhere](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Das scheint nicht zu klappen. I don't want to start a new thread, but to join an existing and on-going one that interests me.

Comment: and it seems as though even this will not work, since I "must have at least 5 reputation" to post it. Na ja... tchüß, denn.

Comment: @RogerMarsh: was hast Du probiert? Bei welchem Thread? Nur bei einer ["protected question"](https://german.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/protect-questions) und bei Kommentaren außerhalb deines eigenen Beitrags brauchst Du Reputationspunkte. Dein Editvorschlag muss von anderen Usern überprüft werden, auch dies nur wegen zuviel Spam in unserem Netz.

Comment: For me, it sounds like there's still a misunderstanding regarding comments and Q&A?

Comment: @hiergiltdiestfu: it may also be a misunderstanding of the basic S.E. principle that we are **not** a discussion forum.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, your question is based on a misunderstanding. You do indeed need 50 reputation points to comment — but commenting does not and never will give you any reputation points at all.

As Takkat already mentioned, the way to gain reputation is to *ask* and *answer* questions. The latter is done by using the text box *Your Answer* below the question. **Only** votes on questions and answers contribute to your reputation score.<sup>[1]</sup>

---

[1]: Alongside accepted edit suggestions and accepting other people’s answers to your own question.